# Convert Canvas object to Imageview Object

Tags: android

I am creating an application in which i have used a method which takes imageView's object as its parameter,but from my code I am getting a canvas object.

So is there any way to convert that canvas object to imageview's object.

Answer (score 1):

> So is there any way to convert that canvas object to imageview's
>   object.

You could convert a canvas to a `Bitmap`:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)width, (int)height, Config.RGB_565));
canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
```

And then use that bitmap to be displayed by an `ImageView`:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```